# How is the direct integral a generalization of the direct sum?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

I have just come across direct integrals so my understanding is shaky, hence I apologize in advance if anything I say is incorrect.

Given a measure space $(X, M, \mu)$ and a collection of separable Hilbert spaces $H_x$, each with inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_x$ we may define the direct integral of the collection $\{H_x\}_{x \in X}$ with respect to $\mu$ to be the collection of all equivalence classes (where the equivalence relation is equality almost everywhere) of functions $f$ such that
$$\|f\|_\oplus = \int_X \langle f(x), f(x)\rangle_x \,d\mu(x) < \infty.$$
We denote this space by
$$\int_X^\oplus H_x\,d\mu(x).$$

The textbook I am using (*Quantum Theory for Mathematicians* By Brian Hall) gives two examples of this construction. The first is if $H_x = \mathbb{C}$ for all $x \in X$, then it is easy to see that the resulting direct integral is simply $L^2(X, \mu)$.

The second example is suppose $X$ is countable, $M$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of all subsets of $X$, and $\mu$ is the counting measure. However this one I am unable to see for myself. How exactly does this hold?

On a side note, why do we even care about this construction in the first place? I see it comes up often in the context of spectral theory, but what exactly motivates its existence?

Comment: If $X$ is a finite set and $\mu$ is the counting measure, this corresponds to the direct sum.

Comment: The reason we want direct sums  is because the direct product $\Pi_{x \in X} H_x$ is far too large when $X$ is infinite: for example if $X$ is countable and each $H_x$ is finite-dimensional then the direct product is uncountably-infinite dimensional. Direct sums (taking only finitely-supporter functions) are a remedy to this in the case where there is no Hilbert space structure available. Direct integrals are a similar remedy taking account of the inner product structure.

Comment: @Joppy Thank you! Would you be able to elaborate a bit more on that? I have always thought of terms direct sum and direct product being synonymous.

Comment: Here's [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2412232/direct-product-vs-direct-sum-of-infinite-dimensional-vector-spaces/2412253#2412253) I wrote some time ago for direct sum versus direct product. I'm not as familiar with the direct integral, but perhaps you can extrapolate yourself from there.